# Escribir dentro de un campo Select

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql-server, options

**Resumen**

Necesito que por medio de un Select el usuario pueda tener la posibilidad de escribir su tipo de organización si es que no esta entre los datos del Select ya registrados por una DB.

**Codigo HTML**

```
                <select class="formulario__input" id="interes" name="interes" required>
                    <option>Seleccione...</option>
                    <?php 
                   $query ="SELECT DISTINCT interes_Datos FROM datosform";

                   $result_Usuario = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_Usuario)){?>
                   
                       <option><?php echo utf8_encode($row['interes_Datos']);?></option>

                   <?php } ?>
                       <option>
                        <!--Aqui necesito poner un option llamado "otro" para el usuario-->
                       </option>
                </select>
```

Si alguien sabe como puedo implementarlo etaria eternamente agradecido  <3 quedo atento ...

Comment: Respuesta corta: No es posible. Sugerencia: Crea un campo que estará oculto por CSS y se muestre cuando se seleccione la opción "Otro".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno los atributos de la etiqueta select option no permiten hacer eso directamente, pero podrías hacerlo con javascript de forma dinamica algo como esto:

```js
let otherText = document.querySelector("#other-text");
let select = document.querySelector("select");

select.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if(select.value == "Otro..."){
    otherText.style.zIndex = 0 + "";
  }else{
    otherText.style.zIndex = -1 + "";
  }
});
```

```css
input{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        left: 8px;
        height: 15px;
        z-index: -1;
        border-right-color: transparent;
}
select{
        width: 130px;
        height: 21px;
        z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>Otro... </option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Otro..." id="other-text">
```

Cuando seleccionas la última opción el input text se coloca por encima del select y cuando seleccionas otra opción se coloca por debajo

Comment: Gracias !
es lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1):

Se hace por medio de un control input asociado a un datalist, de esta manera en vez de ser una lista cerrada te permite escribir valores que no se encuentran en esta, a manera de lista predictiva o de sugerencias.

```
<input class="formulario__input" id="interes" name="interes" required list="interes_list">
<datalist id="interes_list"                        
                    <?php 
                   $query ="SELECT DISTINCT interes_Datos FROM datosform";

                   $result_Usuario = mysqli_query($conexion,$query);
                   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_Usuario)){?>
                   
                       <option><?php echo utf8_encode($row['interes_Datos']);?></option>

                   <?php } ?>                           
    </datalist>
</select>
```

Comment: No hay posibilidad de mostrar un imput dentro del select ? 

he visto formularios que lo implementan asi

Comment: Hay una solución con jquery en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810045/put-input-inside-select

Comment: Es muy buena opción usar `datalist`, el funcionamiento es muy similar al `select`, aunque con unas pequeñas diferencias: no aparece el caracter para indicar que puedes seleccionar y la lista se abre hasta que comienzas a escribir o si el campo está vacío y haces doble clic.

Comment: @Kevins Tal vez te refieras a Select2? https://select2.org/tagging